# How to write to a sidebar menu from another view

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app where there is a sidebar menu. Like the Instagram and Facebook apps, I have a user settings view, where I can upload a picture. This picture is also shown in the sidebar menu. This picture is loaded once, when the sidebar menu tickers `viewdidload`.

The problem is if the user changes the image in the user settings view, I can't get it to update the sidebar menu. The `viewdidload` runs only once.
The best thing would be if i could set the UIimage in the sidebar from the user settings view - but is this even possible?

I not that good at Xcode (swift) yet so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Without code samples or knowing the implementation of your sidebar these are just guesses.  **viewDidLoad** is only called once when the view is added to the hierarchy.  Try moving logic that needs to execute on each subsequent appearance to **viewWillAppear**.

In the past when I've implemented a sidebar, I've used a UITableView or UICollectionView.  This simplified determining what was selected and reloading the state/data of the view as you're using well defined delegates and methods. This worked well for me but YMMV.

> The best thing would be if i could set the UIimage in the sidebar from the user settings view - but is this even possible?

It is probably best to keep your sidebar and settings view separate.  They don't need to know that the other exists.  This doesn't mean they shouldn't share the same data or an abstraction (service class, plist, etc) over that data.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilites to get this done. A non exhausting list:

- [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)
- [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)
- [Delegation](http://sledgedev.com/create-custom-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-objective-c/)

Make your menuVC a delegate for the viewController where your profile-image-change action can be performed. When someone changes the profile-image, call:

```
delegate.profileImageDidChange()
```

In your delegate protocol, you have to define that method of course. Please see the tutorial on Delegation (Hyperlink). If you need more help with implementing it into your code, just ask another question or edit your question.

Comment: Perfect. NSNotificationCenter was just the thing i was looking for.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Please Check the answer of your Choice as correct